# PHP Curl encoding from arabic

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I'm tring to get a webpage in arabic and english using curl and php.

```
<p>الوكالة</p>
<p>Agency</p>
```

The result (immediatly after the curl call) is:

```
<p>???????</p>
<p>Agency</p>
```

I think it's a multi byte problem but I don't know how fix this problem.

Comment: Show your code, without it one can only guess what to suggest.

Comment: And please,check the encoding of your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you shows the text with the correct character encoding (utf 8), try to set following curl option:

```
curl_setopt($var_with_curl_init, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

Comment: and a note to readers, please remove utf8_decode then use the above code